# retrieve international investement fund data

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, google-finance, stockquotes

I am trying to get financial data on bonds and funds not traded in the US.

[Example](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=U1IL.DU&ql=0).

This is my code:

```
import pandas.io.data as web

from datetime import datetime

end = datetime.now()
start = datetime(end.year - 5, end.month, end.day)
df = web.DataReader("U1IL.DU", 'yahoo', start, end)
```

But I always get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/io/data.py", line 177, in _retry_read_url
    rs.index.name = rs.index.name.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rs' referenced before assignment
```

It seems that the `"."` part confuses the program.

Is there a way to enter alternatively

- WKN (German securities identification code) or
- ISIN (International
  Securities Identification Number)

instead of the 4-letter based ticker symbol?

Comment: I'm getting a different error for the query - there seem to be no historical quotes available for this ticker? http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=U1IL.DU&a=00&b=1&c=2015&d=11&e=1&f=2015&g=d

Comment: OK, so it seems that for funds outside US google & yahoo do not provide any data?

Here they have some history
http://www.finanzen.net/fonds/UniRak@inChartZeit_0

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo only covers certain markets & exchanges as laid out [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2310.html).

For German index & equities, SIX is the main provider - overview of securities covered from this geography [here](http://prod1.solid.rolotec.ch/fistats/statistic/country/de).

Note that mutual fund data seem to mainly sourced from [Vickers](http://vickers-stock.com/) with a narrower US focus. I have tried a few German fund tickers without success and would assume that coverage for funds, as opposed to equities, is low to non-existent.